# virtual inheritance issue - warning: 'Sofa' has no out-of-line virtual method definitions; its vtable will be emitted in every translation unit

Tags: c++, c++11

I had an issue for virtual inheritance, it's a sample code for virtual inheritance.

I got the issue as below

warning: 'Sofabed' has no out-of-line virtual method definitions; its vtable will be emitted in every translation unit

Bed and Sofa also got same warning.

How could I fixed this issue?

Run this sample code on

1. Mac OS 10.14.6
2. Qt Creator 4.11.1
3. Based on Qt 5.14.1 (Clang 10.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Furniture { //common base class
protected: int weight;
public: 
    void SetWeight(int a=0) { weight=a; }
    int GetWeight() { return weight; }
    void ShowWeight() { 
        cout << "weight=" << weight << endl;
    } 
};

class Sofa : virtual public Furniture {
public: 
    void sit() { cout << "sit!" << endl; }
    //void ShowWeight() { 
    //    cout << “Sofa weight=” << weight; } 
};

class Bed : virtual public Furniture {
public: 
    void lie() { cout << "lie!" << endl; }
    //void ShowWeight() { 
    //    cout << “Bed weight=” << weight; } 
};

class Sofabed : public Sofa, public Bed {
public: 
    void fold() { cout << "fold!" << endl; }
};


int main() 
{
    Sofabed obj;
    obj.sit();
    obj.lie();
    obj.fold();

    obj.SetWeight(100);
    obj.ShowWeight();

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: After the `#include` block, add `namespace {` and before `main` add the closing `}`.  And never, ever do `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says, you should have at least one virtual function defined in an implementation file (.cpp). Since you should have a virtual destructor in base classes anyway, it is a good candidate for fixing this warning:

Header:

```
class Furniture { //common base class
protected: int weight;
public: 
    virtual ~Furniture();
    void SetWeight(int a=0) { weight=a; }
    int GetWeight() { return weight; }
    void ShowWeight() { 
        cout << "weight=" << weight << endl;
    } 
};
```

Implementation:

```
...
Furniture::~Furniture()
{}
...
```

Comment: ... and if the base class `Furniture` isn't supposed to be instantiable you can make it abstract by making the destructor pure virtual `virtual ~Furniture() = 0;` (but keep the default implementation in the `.cpp` file).

Answer (score 0):

I put all of code in main.cpp.
I tried alain's solution and it still had same issue.

So, I need to using your solution, declare in header file?

But I modified it as below then it works

```
class Furniture { //common base class
protected: int weight;
public:
    void SetWeight(int a=0) { weight=a; }
    int GetWeight() { return weight; }
    void ShowWeight() {
        cout << "weight=" << weight << endl;
    }
};

class Sofa : virtual public Furniture {
public:
    virtual ~Sofa();
    void sit() { cout << "sit!" << endl; }
    //void ShowWeight() {
    //    cout << “Sofa weight=” << weight; }
};

class Bed : virtual public Furniture {
public:
    virtual ~Bed();
    void lie() { cout << "lie!" << endl; }
    //void ShowWeight() {
    //    cout << “Bed weight=” << weight; }
};

class Sofabed : public Sofa, public Bed {
public:
    virtual ~Sofabed();
    void fold() { cout << "fold!" << endl; }
};
```